# Notification about changes to answers

Tags: discussion, editing

As per [this policy](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/making-changes-to-someone-elses-answer) Wouter added information to [this answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11293/programming-differences-between-a-microcontroller-and-a-microprocessor/11294#11294), but unless I missed it I wasn't notified. I see lots of comments in my mailbox, but do I get notified if someone edits an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are no notifications when your posts are edited. Per https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#editing

> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: How can I know if I'm (un)comfortable with it if I don't even know about it? That goes especially for older answers, which I don't check regularly anymore.

Comment: I agree.  It seems a simple notification to the author, like you get when someone comments on your post, is a good idea.  When someone else changes the words that appear to be mine, at least I should be notified.  If nothing else, it tells me the kind of things other wish I'd said differently.  So far I haven't objected to or rolled back any edits others have done on my posts (that I know of), but I think it's only fair I have the opportunity to at least inspect them.

Comment: @olin I believe there might be tools at http://stackapps.com that achieve that for you, much like wikipedia has external tools people use to monitor it.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing that and wondering at the time how Wouter did that since he doesn't have enough reputation to edit other people's posts.  I was going to ask about that here, then forgot.

Personally I think that should have been added as a comment or possibly a answer of his own.  Wouter is very new here and his idea of how things are intended to be done is probably still evolving rapidly.  I know it was a bit confusing and overwhelming for me especially in the first week, and I still don't really feel like I understand all that well yet.  My reaction was to avoid doing things until I understood them better.  Other peoples' reaction may be to try various things.

I know Wouter from the PIClist, and he's a smart guy that usually has good things to say.  If this is something he shouldn't have done, I'm sure that's only because he didn't realize that and somebody should politely tell him.  I'd still like to know how someone with his reputation score managed to edit another's post though.

Comment: I think if you don't have enough rep you still can propose an edit, but that it has to be approved by someone more senior. Which I think is what happened here.

Comment: @steve correct, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: @stevenvh that is correct. It might be beneficial to have a track of who approved what for when something was approved that should not have been.

Comment: @stevenvh, I thought it improved your post without changing its meaning and I was the one that approved it.

Comment: @Kortuk - Yeah, no problem. The reason for my question here is that I'd like to be notified. Not especially about this one, but just any changes.

Comment: @Kellenjb - Personally I don't care that much about who approved it. If I don't agree with it I'd rather talk (in chat) to the one who proposed the change. And I can always rollback, of course.